# Is there a way to extend SASS's functionality?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SASS as my CSS preprocessor.
I would like to use a feature that is not available in SASS - for example, I want to create a function that accepts a reference to an image and will return its width in pixels.

Something like this:
`get-image-width('src/images/logo.png')`

And the same for the image height.
This is just an example. Obviously it can't be done with CSS, so I'm looking for a way to extend SASS and add functionality.

P.S.
I know that Compass supports this feature, but I don't want to use Compass as it's not supported anymore.

Does anyone knows if this is achievable?

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is no, there isn't an easy way.

If you find a module/plugin that works with your current Sass compilation workflow, you could theoretically be able to get the pixel dimensions of an image source and then use certain values somewhere before compiling the final CSS file.

For example, if you are using Gulp, there's the [image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size) package that returns the width/height dimensions. So in a custom Gulp function, you could read the contents of the Sass file, get the dimensions for the image sources you need, use them in whatever context you need, and finally compile the stylesheet.

(Probably no single answer can tell the whole truth regarding your question, so think of this as an extended comment.)